# How can I transpose the row of a table as well as the column names in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, unpivot, lateral-join

I have a table which has only one row like below,
[image]

Here I want to convert the column names to one column and the row into another column, with the column names converted to some predefined numbers as below (A->1E9, B->1E8, ... E->1E5),
[image]

I can't use pivot commands or else. Is there any good way to do this transform? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT 1e9 AS divisor, A AS value
FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT 1e8, B
FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT 1e7, C
FROM yourTable
...
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the quick answer. It works. Thanks! Just a follow up question, what if the original table has a lot of columns, is there a way to automatically to generate the desired table without hard coding the sub-tables to be unioned?

Comment: You can do it with dynamic SQL that gets all the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to unpivot your data using a lateral join:

```
select x.*
from mytable t 
cross join lateral (
    select t.a, 1e9
    union all t.b, 1e8
    union all t.c, 1e7,
    union all t.d, 1e6
    union all t.e, 1e75
) x(divisor, val)
```

The lateral join is more efficient than `union` to solve the question, because it scans the table only once - although if your table has just one row then obviously it won’t make a visible difference.

The feature is available in MySQL starting version 8.0.14.

Comment: The table only has one row, does it really matter how many times it's scanned?

Comment: @Barmar: yes obviously it doesn’t make a difference in this case… I edited my question to mention it. Still, it’s maybe worth promoting the use of recent MySQL features (lateral joins had been missing in MySQL for a long time)?