# SQL query to convert a single Row with multiple status change date columns into multiple rows with status and timestamp

Tags: sql, mysql, hive

I have my input data like below :

| story_id | sched_state | story_being_groomed_ts | story_def_ts | story_in_prgrs_ts | story_cmpl_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | completed | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-20 | 2023-01-23 |
| 2 | inprogress | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-30 |  |

And I want my output to be like :

There are total 4stages (Groomed, defined, inprogress and completed) based on time stamp availability we need to update the stages in output.

| story_id | sched_state | last_up_ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Groomed | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | Defined | 2023-01-13 |
| 1 | inprogress | 2023-01-20 |
| 1 | Completed | 2023-01-23 |
| 2 | Groomed | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | Defined | 2023-01-10 |
| 2 | inprogress | 2023-01-30 |

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: search for mysql unpivot

Comment: hive ? or mysql ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I transpose the row of a table as well as the column names in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922296/how-can-i-transpose-the-row-of-a-table-as-well-as-the-column-names-in-mysql). Assuming MySQL 8, use the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` approach, as it is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not direct way to unpivot in mysql. It can be done as below:

```
select story_id, sched_state, last_up_ts
from (
    select t.story_id,
      c.sched_state,
      case c.sched_state
        when 'Groomed' then story_being_groomed_ts
        when 'defined' then story_def_ts
        when 'inprogress' then story_in_prgrs_ts
        when 'completed' then story_cmpl_ts
      end as last_up_ts
    from mytable t
    cross join
    (
      select 'Groomed' as sched_state
      union all select 'defined'
      union all select 'inprogress'
      union all select 'completed'
    ) c
) sub
where last_up_ts is not null 
ORDER BY story_id, sched_state, last_up_ts
```